# Issues with CanCan authorization - Author edits Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization, cancan

I'm working on a Rails app, authorization using CanCan. The app has the db models User and PositionGameStat. The PositionGameStat has a foreign key of user_id. The index page for position_game_stat shows a list of Stats that the user has submitted, each one with an edit button. Currently it is vulnerable to injection (... /position_game_stats/130/edit)

I would like the user to only be able to edit position_game_stat entries equal to current user.

In other words if someone tried to inject into the url .../position_game_stats/129/edit and they did not enter those stats, it would be denied access by CanCan

Below is my code.

My Code:
app/controllers/position_game_stats_controller.rb

```
class PositionGameStatsController < ApplicationController  

    before_filter :authenticate_user! 
    ...   
    def edit
      authorize! :manage, @position_game_stat 
      @position_game_stat = PositionGameStat.find(params[:id])
    end 
    ... 
  end
```

app/models/ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :show, User, :id => user.id
    can :manage, PositionGameStat do |t|
      t.user_id == user.id
    end  
  end 
end
```

Any suggestions are well appreciated.

UPDATE:
as per Billy Chan's suggestion seem to be at least somewhat closer with this code:
Ability

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :show, User, :id => user.id
    can :manage, PositionGameStat do |t|
      t.user == current_user
    end
  end
end
```

Controller

```
class PositionGameStatsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

...

  def edit
    authorize! :manage, PositionGameStat
    @position_game_stat = PositionGameStat.find(params[:id])
  end
...
end
```

This got me closer in the sense that it is not denying access to the page however it is still vulnerable to injection. For instance /position_game_stats/137/edit is still accessible even through it was created by a different user.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why are you authorizing `@position_game_stat` before it's been assigned a value? What exactly is the issue you're having?

Comment: The issue I am having is that the authorization is stopping the user from editing a position_game_stat. I got it working for 'user' so that you are unable to inject a different user value into the params, but now it I am working with a foreign key and I am having trouble when using the position_game_stat model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution:
PositionGameStatsController.rb

```
    class PositionGameStatsController < ApplicationController

      before_filter :authenticate_user!

      load_and_authorize_resource

...

      def edit
        authorize! :manage, PositionGameStat
        @position_game_stat = PositionGameStat.find(params[:id])
      end
...
    end
```

Ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :show, User, :id => user.id
    can :manage, PositionGameStat do |t|
      t.user.id == user.id
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you both Billy Chan and Steakchaser for your suggestions, it was enough to get me going. current_user does not work in Ability.rb for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

In your ability.rb you need to specify how the authorization rules should be applied:

```
  can :manage, PositionGameStat, PositionGameStat.find_all_by_user_id(user.id) do |position_game_stat|
    position_game_stat.new_record? or position_game_stat.user.id == user.id
  end
```

In your controller you can then have the authorization applied by using:

```
  load_and_authorize_resource
```

NOTE: load_and_authorize_resource actuall does things like `@position_game_stat = PositionGameStat.find(params[:id])`.  If you don't want this behavior, you can perform the authorization manually like this:

```
  @position_game_stat = PositionGameStat.accessible_by(current_ability).find(params[:id])
```

Lastly refer to this portion of the CanCan docs for more details: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks

Comment: Got the error undefined method `include?' for #<PositionGameStat:0x007fb117473180>

Comment: Can you put load_and_authorize_resource at the top of the controller def; before any of the actions?

Comment: I think my load statement for '@position_game_stat' is bad.  Take that out or just make it the standard @position_game_stat = PositionGameStat.find(params[:id]).

Comment: when I have load_and_authorize_resource at the top of my position_game_stat_controller the error happens before the code under def edit even loads. I am looking at this right now https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources
 and try some options.

Comment: yeah I've tried many different options and I keep running into this issue with 'load_and_authorize_resource'

Answer (score 0):

```
can :manage, PositionGameStat do |t|
  t.user == current_user
end
```

Done.

*Update*

Okay, I see the problem. This line is wrong

```
authorize! :manage, @position_game_stat
```

You authorize this specific instance only. That is wrong. Should be

```
authorize! :manage, PositionGameStat
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work for me, CanCan is still denying access.

Comment: @lando2319, do you have `current_user` method ready? Either from Devise or your own.

Comment: Actually I just noticed it is still susceptible to injection. For instance /position_game_stat/137/edit is accessible even though it was from a different user. I'll keep working on it.